# Xamarin.Forms Android project breaks when installing Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I've been working on a Xamarin application, testing on my Android device as well as my Windows PC. It was all working well, but then I came to a point where I had to add Maps integration to the app. I followed the steps as outlined on the Xamarin developer website, installing the Xamarin.Forms.Maps nuget package, but this has caused my Android project to refuse to build.

First it took more than an hour stuck trying to build, after which I decided to cancel the build, now it gives me an error of 'resource.attribute does not contain a definition for actionbarsize'.

Comment: Do you have API 23 installed? Which API is the build target?

Comment: I was targeting API 15 as a minimum.  Have all the necessary APIs installed. I made it work by installing an older version of Xamarin.Forms.Maps form nuget, alongside older versions of the Android packages. Had to go for version 23.0.1.3 on the Android specific packages, and 2.0.0.6482 on the Xamarin.Forms.Maps package.